# How to controll how value.ToString works in DataGridViewTextBoxColumn?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Having something like such `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`:

```
var decayTimeColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
  DataPropertyName = "DecayTimeUi",
  HeaderText = @"half-life"
};
```

That works on top of `List<T>` where T has `.DecayTimeUi` geter returning float how to controll the way it is displayed (set its `value.ToString("E", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead of default `ToString`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) of the cell through the [`DefaultCellStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.defaultcellstyle.aspx):

```
var decayTimeColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn {
  DataPropertyName = "DecayTimeUi",
  HeaderText = @"half-life",
  DefaultCellStyle.Format = "E"
};
```

It only supports a string, though, so no strongly-typed culture can be specified in that way; you'd need to find a shorthand formatting string that applies to you circumstance.

Comment: cant even set DefaultCellStyle - compilation error (on code you provided): `Error The name 'DefaultCellStyle' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Then can you do: `DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle { Format = "E" }`, or not?

Comment: I can do it as next line: `            decayTimeColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "E";`, compiles, works.